# Insert password hash using PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a basic mysql insert you are able to set a password variable 'PASSWORD($password)' but this breaks a PDO statement.

How do you hash the password while using pdo::prepare and pdo::execute?

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO contractors (userid, password, name) VALUES ('$userid', '$pass1', '$name')";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$count = $result->execute();

Echo $count."<br>";
```

I am such a n00b, a simple registration page has taken me two days. Kindergarten answers are welcomed.

thanks,

Comment: You should be using bindParam() to put in those parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to hash using MD5, you could do the following with the password before constructing the SQL statement:

```
$pass1 = md5($pass1);
$sql = "INSERT INTO contractors ( userid, password, name ) VALUES ( '$userid', '$pass1', '$name' )";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$count = $result->execute();

echo $count."<br>";
```

The idea is the same even if it is another hash function. Hash the password before constructing the SQL statement.

As [Fiarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156200/fiarr) and [VoteyDisciple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153980/voteydisciple) have noted in the comments below, opt for a SHA hash as it is more secure.

[sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)

Comment: With the above, I'd suggest using SHA (as it's less cracked), and using a salt.

Comment: Yes, SHAs are probably better, especially with a salt. (I use them personally.)

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly: this deliberately doesn't use MySQL's `PASSWORD()` function.  `PASSWORD()` is intended only for MySQL's own use, not for developers creating passwords within their applications.  `md5()` or `sha1()` work essentially the same way, but are more secure.  You can call either function from PHP or from MySQL.

Comment: figures it was a cheap online class that was using PASSWORD(). Thanks for the tip and the help. I will study sha1(). 
Thanks to Alan and Fiarr. I appreciate it.

Comment: SHA1 is better than MD5 but SHA1 has also been weakened by cracks.  New recommendation from NIST is SHA-256, but the patch I submitted to MySQL got implemented in MySQL 6.0.5, which is probably still many months away from being released.

Comment: Also SHA-256 is supported in PHP, cf. the `hash()` function.

Comment: -1 - As Joe Phillips mentioned, he should be using placeholders

Comment: Passwords should never be hashed using MD5. PHP's `password_hash()` function does the job very well. Also, using a prepared statement will remove the risk of SQL-injection

Answer (score 13):

> #### Note
>
> This answer originally recommended an unsalted hash.  That's silly nowadays, so it's been rewritten to bring it into the modern era.  Watch out for similar now-bad answers in older content here on SO.

You're using PDO, so you should be using parameterized queries with placeholders:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO contractors (userid, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$count = $result->execute(array($userid, $pass1, $name));

echo $count."<br>";
```

In the modern era, you should us **Blowfish/bcrypt** instead of MD5 or SHA1.  As of PHP 5.3, you can use [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) with the `$2y$` prefix.  As of PHP 5.5, you'll be able to use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) instead.  You can use [ircmaxell's password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) in the mean time.

Here's a demo using `crypt` and a *very low* difficulty value.  Note that we're also storing the salt.  While I've hard-coded the salt here in this demo, you should use a unique salt per user.

```
$salt = 'saltysaltsaltsalt'; 
$password_hash = crypt($pass1, '$2a$07$' . $salt);
$sql= "INSERT INTO contractors (userid, password, salt, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$count = $result->execute(array($userid, $password_hash, $salt, $name));

echo $count."<br>";
```

Verifying the password is as easy as reconstructing the hash using the same parameters.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT password, salt FROM contractors WHERE userid = ?');
$sth->execute(array($userid));
list($existing_hash, $salt) = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
unset($sth);

$new_hash = crypt($pass1, '$2a$07$' . $salt);
if($new_hash === $existing_hash) {
    echo "Password matched.";
} else {
    echo "Password did not match.";
}
```

Comment: Well done, beat me to it.  You said it better than I did, too.

Comment: I think your execute() parameter needs to be an array

Comment: This is easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368038/crypt-salt-generation-and-password-encryption-well-executed#answer-20370991

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = new PDOStatement();

  $hash = sha1($pass . $dataUniqueToEachUser);
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(name, email, hash) VALUES (:name, :email, :hash)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

  if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
   $valid = true;
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "An error occurred: {$e}";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps more safe if you create your own hash (and perhaps more simple tough). The best sollution, in my oppinion, is to create a hash by joining several fields from the table, like this:

```
$pass1 = sha1($pass1.$name);
```

Note: md5, as suggested above, isn't the saffest sollution, since currently there's a lot of databases over the internet with keywords associated to md5 hash variables, making it easier to someone who wants to hack your system.

Comment: Simply concatenating multiple variable-length fields in lieu of salt can leave your application open to some unusual impersonation attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Using variable substitution like that makes your app *wide* open to SQL injection attacks, unless you are escaping $userid and the lot before the code you pasted.

Better to use PDO's substitution abilities (I mean, you're already calling .prepare):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contractors (userid, password, name) VALUES (?, PASSWORD(?), ?)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$dbh->execute(array($userid, $pass1, $name));
```

I'm not sure if inlining PASSWORD() like that will work -- please correct me if I'm wrong.  If you want to take Alan's approach and not rely on MySQL to hash your passwords (wise), you can also do something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contractors (userid, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$dbh->execute(array($userid, sha1($hashed), $name));
```

Consider using a salt as well:

```
$hashed = sha1("SaltedPassword" . $pass1);
```

Comment: Even better would be to use bindParam() I think

Comment: IMO, bindParam() is silly.  Only PHP does it that way, and it makes the code less elegant.

Comment: It's silly if you plan on never making changes to your code. Relying on indices to match the parameters where they need to go is never a brilliant idea IMO