# Empty Array when executing the SQL statement using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am am following a tutorial for MVC and I am stuck in a position where I can't go further.

The problem is that when I am executing the SQL Statement, I am trying to get the value and just print it/echo it.

I have a function where I am achieving it. Here's the code for it :

NOTE : I am using filter_input() method to get the $_POST(['login']) and $_POST(['password']). For some reason, I can't directly use $_POST() method because it giving me a warning for don't access superglobal $_POST directly.

I am not sure what exactly is the issue here. I am getting zero for this and I actually have one entry in the database.

```
public function run(){

        $login =         filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login');
        $password =      filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE 
                login = :login AND password = MD5(:password)");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':login' => $login,
            ':password' => $password
        ));

        $data = $sth->fetchAll(); 
        print_r($data);
    /*$count = $sth->rowCount();
    print_r($count);

    if($count>0){

        echo 'Have a record.';

    }else{

        echo 'No Record found.';

    }*/

    }
```

If someone can help me find the issue, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: If someone does a down vote, it's better to add a comment for the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [*manual*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php),

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

**After update:** Try below,

```
 $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE 
                login = :login AND password = :password");

 $sth->execute(array(
            ':login' => $login,
            ':password' => md5($password)
        ));
 $data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: That's right..:) but even if I remove the count, The Array is still Zero and if the uncomment the line $data = $sth->fetchAll();, I can see that the Array Value is zero. I used the count method just to test if I am actually getting values or not.

Comment: First do `md5` and than bind that variable [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382215/insert-password-hash-using-pdo-prepared-statements).

Comment: Thanks Rikesh.. but I am not that familiar with php much and just learning.. can you show me how should I do that.. It will be helpful.